# Better pandas performance profiling

Tags: python, pandas, profiling

Is there a better way to profile the performance of a large code base that uses pandas?

Currently if I use standard tools like `cProfile` and even when using `gprof2dot` the call stacks for pandas aren't very informative. As an example I might get a result such as `common:67:new_method 77.87%` which just tells me some comparisons in the code are taking the most time, the problem here is it doesn't tell me where. I can provide many similar examples which makes performance profiling pandas a pain. I'd like a more granular way to profile my code that tells me where the problems are. One such example is below:

[image: Example call stack]

Google and stack overflow searching for pandas profiling doesn't help much as the results are for profiling a data set and not the performance.

Comment: This very much depends on what information you are looking for, but here are a couple of suggestions I found useful in the past: 
You can try `scalene` to analyse whole programs, it gives information about CPU, GPU and memory usage.
If you care about memory taken up by your dataframes, I recommend `ydata-profiling`; for time-wise performance of individual functions, I was quite happy with `line_profiler`.